# c++; can't start just built VS2013 exe with debugger but can without

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

Just built VS2013 c++ solution.  Pressing F5 (start debugging) results in error dialog stating "Unable to start program 'C:\path\myApp.exe'". Meanwhile starting w/o debugging (CTRL+F5) starts myApp running just fine. The same happens with both Debug, and Release builds.

Up until a few hours ago everything was fine and I have not (consciously) changed any of VS settings. I already checked that target path in project settings is specified correctly and am at a loss where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Reboot fixed it. I have not seen problems fixable by reboot for some time.